# How to implement NOT operation in MIPS?

Tags: mips, mips32

I am new in MIPS, and I am trying to judge whether each char in a string is an alpha. I used the ASCII code to help me to judge it, while I found there is no instruction representing `larger than` meaning. So I try to implement a `not` operation from the instructions I have known. Here's part of my code:

```
isAlpha:
  sltiu $t0, $s2, 123
  sltiu $t1, $s2, 97
  nor $t1, $t1, $t1
  and $t0, $t0, $t1

  sltiu $t2, $s2, 107
  sltiu $t3, $s2, 81
  nor $t3, $t3, $t3
  and $t2, $t2, $t3

  or $t0, $t0, $t2

  bne $t0, $zero, countAlpha
  jr $ra
```

However, I could not get the result I want. I set a breakpoint and found that my `not` operation seems to have some problems:
[image: After judge]

In my exception, $t1 should be 1 and $t2 should be 0, while the reality is not.

Where's the wrong place in my code? Is there any way to implement `not` operation in MIPS? Or is there a better way to implement `larger than` meaning in MIPS? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a not operation here:

```
nor $t1, $t1, $t1
```

Often you can just type the `not` mnemonic and your assembler will interpret it as a [pseudo instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_instruction_set#Pseudo_instructions)

I think you want an exclusive or operation to tell you if your input is just one of less than 123 and less than 97.

Something like this (totally untested)

```
isAlpha:
  sltiu $t0, $s2, 123
  sltiu $t1, $s2, 97
  xor $t0, $t0, $t1

  sltiu $t2, $s2, 107
  sltiu $t3, $s2, 81
  xor $t2, $t2, $t3

  or $t0, $t0, $t2

  bne $t0, $zero, countAlpha
  jr $ra
```

Comment: I created an answer for this, but before posting, I found yours. I was almost going to not post mine [which had an additional `and` instruction] because I came to think yours was sufficient--and upvote your's. Then, I realized the edge case I was worried about was real. But, +1 for you anyway. See my answer for the what/why

Comment: @Craig Estey You say in your answer "xor of two zeros is 1", are you sure?

Comment: I guess I was sleep deprived that day :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the effect of `gt` by reversing the arguments to `slt*`:

```
    sltu   $v0,$t0,$t1             # v0 = $t0 < $t1 (what you have)
    sltu   $v0,$t1,$t0             # v0 = $t0 > $t1 (what you want)
```

Note that `ge` or `le` is a bit trickier. Consider the various branch pseudo ops like: `blt, bge, bgt, bge` [they generate `slt*` followed by either `beq` or `bne`]. They're usually easier to work with.

`xor` can do bitwise negation. The `not` pseudo-op will generate a `nor`.

Below is some code that does what you want. Note that it is similar to the code sfi posted, but has an additional [and necessary] `and` during the range check to prevent a false positive.

For example, *without* the `and`, the range check for `a-z` will report true on anything higher than `z` (e.g. `0x7B` aka `{`). This is because both `slt` instructions will generate 0. But, `xor` of two zeros is 1. So, the `xor` result must be anded against the high range value `slt` result

```
# isAlpha -- decide if char is alpha
#
# RETURNS:
#   v0 -- 1=is alpha
#   s6 -- count of alpha chars
#
# arguments:
#   s2 -- character to test
#
# registers:
#   t0 -- holds lt 'a/A'? value
#   t1 -- holds lt 'a/A' + 1? value
#   t2 -- bool for within 'a-z'
#   t3 -- bool for within 'A-Z'
isAlpha:
    # within a-z range
    sltiu   $t0,$s2,0x61            # lt 'a'? (i.e. not a-z)
    sltiu   $t1,$s2,0x7B            # lt 'z' + 1? (i.e. le 'z')
    xor     $t2,$t0,$t1             # want one but not both
    and     $t2,$t2,$t1             # want only lt 'z' + 1

    # within A-Z range
    sltiu   $t0,$s2,0x41            # lt 'A'? (i.e. not A-Z)
    sltiu   $t1,$s2,0x5C            # lt 'Z' + 1? (i.e. le 'Z')
    xor     $t3,$t0,$t1             # want one but not both
    and     $t3,$t3,$t1             # want only lt 'Z' + 1

    or      $v0,$t2,$t3             # decide if alpha
    add     $s6,$s6,$v0             # increment alpha count
    jr      $ra
```